# How to find API key of an apk. file?

Tags: android, api, apk, api-key

I have an .apk file and I want to find the API key of it in UUID format. Because I don't know, where can it be stored, I am asking here.

I tried to decompile it and then find it in AndroidManifest.xml, but it wasn't there. The .apk is programmed in Kotlin, so I tried to convert it to Java, but it didn't also tell me anything.

Where can someone place an API key in .apk file when he tries to hide it?

Comment: That depends on the SDK. Most SDKs simply store it in a configuration file, often placed in the root directory of the APK file. If no SDK is used the key can be placed anywhere in any format (plain text, obfuscated, encrypted or in whatever format). If you know the key is in UUID format you can try to bild an regular expression for UUID-like strings and apply it to the decompiled sources (e.g. decompile it with `apktool`). May be extracting the key from the network traffic would be easier if you can not find the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this task using grep:

```
grep -a -E '\b[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}\b' .
```

-a is for searching in binary files so I did not have to decompile the apk file using apktool or something else.